# Use custom dialogs in Flutter FutureBuilder waiting

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

I have a request to the server, when I use FutureBuilder, the ConnectionState.waiting section, I want to use a custom dialog, but after ConnectionState.done, this dialog does not close, it does not even do Navigator.pop(context).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icmeO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icmeO.png)

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to disable Alert Dialog using object orientation, and I designed dialogs on a separate page, and Navigator.pop() does not work, but with this method, I achieved my desired result.

```
  FutureBuilder(
   future: _futureEditName,
   builder: (context,snapshot){
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          ShowWaitingDialog(context,true);

      }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){
         ShowWaitingDialog(context,false)
      }
   }

);
```

show and dismiss Alert Dialog

```
ShowWaitingDialog(BuildContext context,bool show) {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return show == true ?
    AlertDialog(
      insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      title: Container(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Column(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          children: [
            Row(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              children: [
                const SpinKitCircle(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  size: 35,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text(
                    'please wait',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kGraydark,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    : FutureBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      return Container();
    },);
},);
```

}

```
Navigator.of(context).pop() It must be called twice
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Before `ConnectionState.waiting` just call this `onLoading(context);`

then

```
if(ConnectionState. done){
  Navigator.pop();
}



void onLoading(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue));
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but Unfortunately with `Navigator.of(context).pop()` Alert Dialog not dismiss

Comment: Did u try my answer ?

Comment: Yes, I tested but it didn't work